# How to add roles to claims in IdentityServer4?

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I am new to IdentityServer and I have been struggling with this issue all day. So much so that I'm almost about to give up on this. I know this question has been asked over and over again and I have tried many different solutions but none seem to work. Hopefully you can help me push me in the right direction with this.

First I installed the IdentityServer4 templates by running `dotnet new -i identityserver4.templates` and created a new project with the is4aspid template by running `dotnet new is4aspid -o IdentityServer`.

After that i created a new IdentityServer database and ran the migrations. By that time I had a the default Identity database structure.

In Config.cs I changed `MVC client` to the following:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("47C2A9E1-6A76-3A19-F3C0-S37763QB36D9".Sha256()) },

    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44307/signin-oidc" },
    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44307/signout-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44307/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "api1", JwtClaimTypes.Role }                
},
```

And changed the `GetApis` method to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
{
    return new ApiResource[]
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API #1", new List<string>() { "role" })
    };
}
```

There where of course no users in the database yet so i added a registration form and registered two dummy users, one with the username `admin@example.com` and one with the username `subscriber@example.com`.

To assign the roles to these user I created the following method in Startup.cs.

```
private async Task CreateUserRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

    IdentityResult adminRoleResult;
    IdentityResult subscriberRoleResult;

    bool adminRoleExists = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
    bool subscriberRoleExists = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Subscriber");

    if (!adminRoleExists) {
        adminRoleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
    }

    if(!subscriberRoleExists) {
        subscriberRoleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Subscriber"));
    }

    ApplicationUser userToMakeAdmin = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("admin@example.com");
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userToMakeAdmin, "Admin");

    ApplicationUser userToMakeSubscriber = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync("subscriber@example.com");
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userToMakeSubscriber, "Subscriber");
}
```

In the `Configure` method of the same class I add the the parameter `IServiceProvider services` and called the above method like so: `CreateUserRoles(services).Wait();`. By this time my database did have two roles in it.

Next I created a new solution (within the same project) and in the Startup.cs file of that solution I added the following in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "32D7A7W0-0ALN-2Q44-A1H4-A37990NN83BP";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role");
        });
```

After that I added `app.UseAuthentication();` in the `Configure` method of the same class.

Then I created a new page with the following if statements.

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
 <div>Yes, user is authenticated</div>
} 

if(User.IsInRole("ADMIN")) {
 <div>Yes, user is admin</div>
}
```

I logged in with `admin@example.com` but the second if statement returns `False`. I inspected all the claims by looping over them like so.

```
@foreach (var claim in User.Claims) {
    <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
    <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
}
```

But there was no role claim to be found, only sid, sub, idp, preferred_username and name.

I tried to get the role in there so that the second if statement returns True but after trying and trying I have not yet been able to make it work. Can someone see what I have to do in order to make this work? I am an absolute beginner in IdentityServer4 and trying my best to understand it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks to [this question](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1786) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976553/identityserver4-role-based-authorization-for-web-api-with-asp-net-core-identity/53977681#53977681) I got the feeling that I'm on the right track. I have made some modifications but I still can not get it to work. I just tried the following.

1. Created a new ProfileService class in my IdentityServer project with the following content.

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService {
 public MyProfileService() { }
 public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context) {
  var roleClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
  List<string> list = context.RequestedClaimTypes.ToList();
  context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
  return Task.CompletedTask;
 }

 public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context) {
  return Task.CompletedTask;
 }
}
```

Next I registered this class in the ConfigureServices method by adding the line `services.AddTransient<IProfileService, MyProfileService>();`. After that I added a new a new line to the GetIdentityResources method, which looks like this now.

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
{
    return new IdentityResource[]
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        new IdentityResource("roles", new[] { "role" })
};
}
```

I also added the roles to my Mvc client like so: `AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "api1", "roles" }`.

Next I switched over to the other project and added the following lines in the .AddOpenIdConnect oidc.

```
options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
```

But still, I cannot get it to work like I want it to. Anyone knows what I am missing?

Comment: Search for this exact question, I answered it already here on SO, just can’t check now on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have indeed seen your answer and tried to implement your solution. However the second if statement still returns False and the role is not part of the claims. I have edited my post with the code I added. If you can explain me what I'm doing wrong it will be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks good so far, I will take a wild guess and say that it's case sensitive maybe, so try `IsInRole("Admin")`. Also inspect the raw token using something like https://jwt.io and check if the `role` claim is now added correctly to the token. Also you haven't implemented your `ProfileService` as per my answer.

Comment: @Mitch, can't see `options.ResponseType = "id_token token";` in your client side config, so you request only `IdentityResiource` information and not `ApiResource`. nevettheless after your edit you should be able to get your roles with the id_token, but you have to request that explicitly: `options.Scope.Add("roles");`

Comment: Unfortunately neither of them is the case. No matter if I change isInRole("ADMIN") to isInRole("Admin") ot to isInRole("admin"), they all return False. The decoded JWT token also does not contain a role key.

However if I add options.Scope.Add("roles"); to the client side it returns the role attribute and the isInRole("Admin") return true!

Thanks for your suggestions and help! It works like it should now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Slightly different question, absolutely matching answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033154/asp-net-core-2-1-openidconnectoptions-with-scope-doesnt-work)

With the **Edit 1**, IdP configuration looks enough to supply both *identity* and *access* tokens with roles *when requested*. The only thing left is to configure the client to request the access token (.Net client doesn't do that by default), or just request the `roles` scope within the identity token.

To get the roles with `id_token`, the client side config must include `options.Scope.Add("roles");`

To get the roles with bearer token, that token must be requested by specifying `options.ResponseType = "id_token token";` in client side config.

Answer (score 8):

Two things you need to do to make sure you will get users roles in the claims:

1- In IdentityServer4 project: you need to have implementation for IProfileService
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html

don't forget to add the class in startup.cs file like this

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
// I just removed some other configurations for clarity
                **.AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>();**
```

2- In Web Client project's startup.cs file: when configuring the openId, you have to mention this :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.Authority = "Identity URL ";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

            options.ClientId = "saas_crm_webclient";
            options.ClientSecret = "49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB86B0";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;

            options.Scope.Add("test.api");
            options.Scope.Add("identity.api");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");


            **options.ClaimActions.Add(new JsonKeyClaimAction("role", null, "role"));**

            **options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            };**
        });
```

Comment: 1 - is not required, 2 - will not work, you forgot to add a scope `options.Scope.Add("roles");` where "roles" should match with the role name in the IdentityServer. I also found the name "role" can conflict with the role type (which is "role"), so it might be a problem, so better to name this claim scope "roles" instead of "role", as in the code example of the topic starter. Also, `RoleClaimType` should match with with the role type set in the IS4, so `UserClaims = new[] { JwtClaimTypes.Role };` in IS4 and `RoleClaimType = "JwtClaimTypes.Role"` in MVC client respectively will work better.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this in .NET 5:

Add `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` before `services.AddAuthentication` in `Startup.cs`.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1349

I also added

```
services.AddScoped<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
```

and `ProfileService.cs` that looks like this to map roles to claims:

```
public sealed class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _userClaimsPrincipalFactory;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userMgr;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleMgr;

    public ProfileService(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userMgr,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleMgr,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> userClaimsPrincipalFactory)
    {
        _userMgr = userMgr;
        _roleMgr = roleMgr;
        _userClaimsPrincipalFactory = userClaimsPrincipalFactory;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        string sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        ApplicationUser user = await _userMgr.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        ClaimsPrincipal userClaims = await _userClaimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);

        List<Claim> claims = userClaims.Claims.ToList();
        claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();

        if (_userMgr.SupportsUserRole)
        {
            IList<string> roles = await _userMgr.GetRolesAsync(user);
            foreach (var roleName in roles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
                if (_roleMgr.SupportsRoleClaims)
                {
                    IdentityRole role = await _roleMgr.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
                    if (role != null)
                    {
                        claims.AddRange(await _roleMgr.GetClaimsAsync(role));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        string sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        ApplicationUser user = await _userMgr.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        context.IsActive = user != null;
    }
}
```

Source:

https://ffimnsr.medium.com/adding-identity-roles-to-identity-server-4-in-net-core-3-1-d42b64ff6675